# How can I tell a dynamically created TextView's position in a table layout?

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

I have a table layout of textviews that I am making on the fly based on input. I want to set it so that when the user clicks on that textview/box, it will do something based on the row and column position of that textview. So, for example, if the one clicked is in row (1,2), create my second activity for 1vs2 in the string extras.

The issue is that I'm creating these columns and rows dynamically, so I don't know how wide it can be, and I don't want to set the text to its position, for that's supposed to show values there. The only thing I can think of is to set the ID to a specific number. For example, 12 means row 1, column 2. However, this becomes a problem. if we do more than ten. as in (11,2) = 112, is that row 1 or row 11 then?

What's the best way to do this?

Here's how they're created:

```
  //add cells
        for (int k = 0; k < arrFencers.size() + 5; k++) {

            //get table layout count

                TextView tempCell = new TextView(this);
                tempCell.setClickable(true);
                tempCell.setText("_");
                tempCell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custombb);
                //  tempCell.setId("");


                tempCell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //This doesn't work~~
                        String data = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String[] IDs = data.split("-");

                        //Get names
                        String[] names = {arrFencers.get(Integer.parseInt(IDs[0]) - 1),
                                arrFencers.get(Integer.parseInt(IDs[1]) - 1)};
                        //setup bout Sheet data
                        String[] boutData = {IDs[0], names[0], IDs[1], names[1]};

                        //create new bout sheet
                        Intent bIntent = new Intent("hss.quickpool.bout");
                        bIntent.putExtra("boutData", boutData);

                        startActivityForResult(bIntent, 1);

                    }
                });

                //add to table row
                newFencer.addView(tempCell);

        }
```

Comment: the simplest approach will be to use `setTag` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29 for view identification

Comment: @nikis this worked for me! Feel free to write an answer and I can give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `View` object has [setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) method for storing generic user data, so it can be used for the view identification purpose like so:

```
class Position{
    int mRow;
    int mColumn;

    public Position(int row, int column) {
        this.mRow = row;
        this.mColumn = column;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return mRow;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return mColumn;
    }
}

...
Position position = new Position(5, 10);
myTextView.setTag(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use setTag(Object o)  on each View of the table.
and store information in that object.

Define a simple class for storing data:

```
public static class MyData{
public final int rowI;
public final int columnI;


public MyData(int row, int column) {
    rowI = row;
    columnI = column;

}
```

}

set the tag on each cell:

```
tempcell.setTag(new MyData(i, j));
```

and retrieve data in onClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
MyData mData = (MyData) v.getTag();
if (null != mData) {
    v.setText(mData.rowI.toString + "," + mData.columnI.toString);
}
```

}